# Get XML attribute with C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file like the following.

```
<div class="time">
   <span class="title">Bla: </span>
   <span class="value">Thu 20 Jan 11</span>
</div>
```

How can I get value "Thu 20 Jan 11" with C#? 
thanks in advance

Comment: are those the names of the xml nodes <div> <span> ?

Comment: This sounds more like HTML to me...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you rather need an HTML Parser IMHO.
if so, then Take a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to parse an Atom RSS feed which has nested html code like the above:(

Answer (score 1):

Given that you do have an XML file like you say, then you need could load the file into an XmlDocument and find what you want using XPath:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = "<div class=\"time\">" +
                        "<span class=\"title\">Bla: </span>" +
                        "<span class=\"value\">Thu 20 Jan 11</span>" +
                        "</div>";
            var document = new XmlDocument();

            try
            {
                document.LoadXml(xml);
            }
            catch (XmlException xe)
            {
                // Handle and/or re-throw
                throw;
            }

            var date = document.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class = 'value']").InnerText;

            Console.WriteLine(date);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Output: Thu 20 Jan 11

Comment: Or if you need to be more specific and requiring span to be in a div with that specific class then use XPath:  
//div[@class='time']/span[@class='value']

Comment: Hi, i've tried your code and it working perfectly as it is .... but when I am trying to load an Atom RSS feed which has nested html ... it throws "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little snippet, which does it for you...

```
public void Test(String source)
{

XElement elem = XElement.Parse(source);

var query = (from x in elem.Descendants("span") select x.Value).LastOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
}
```

Comment: When I ran your code it gives me an "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: Tested in LinqPad with query.Dump() and works just fine. Don`t forget to escape these '"' in the source-String, like this "<div class=\"time\">...

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath queries may be an elegant solution too. See this knowledge base article for a brief how-to: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

This of course requires the document to be strictly correct XML, which XHTML is. Unfortunately HTML input often contains syntax errors...

Cheers,
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

As said you could parse it as HTML.

However treating it as a XML document you can read the value from the node  by using the XPath: 
**/div/span[@class="value"]**

You can also use XDocument to select a node value from a known XPath or by searching through descendant nodes. Using LINQ this becomes very easy to match on attribute value. [Link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is as sgrassie's answer but using linq to xml, I like more this code, but is up to you.

```
string xml = "<div class=\"time\"><span class=\"title\">Bla: </span><span class=\"value\">Thu 20 Jan 11</span></div>";
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
var date = xdoc.Element("div").Elements("span").Where(m => ((string)m.Attribute("class")) == "value").FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(date.Value);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: - <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <updated>2011-01-20T08:33:23Z</updated>
  <title type="html">grgrgr</title>
  - <entry>
    <title type="html">Blog post : Estiatoria</title>
    - <content type="xhtml">
      - <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        - <div class="due">
          <span class="title">Due:</span>
          <span class="value">20 Jan 11</span>
        </div>
      </content>
  </entry>
</feed>

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code in VTD-XML:

```
  VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
  System.Text.Encoding eg = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
    String XML = "<div class=\"time\">" +                         
                 "<span class=\"title\">Bla: </span>" +                     
                 "<span class=\"value\">Thu 20 Jan 11</span>" +                     
                 "</div>";
    vg.setDoc(eg.GetBytes(XML));
    vg.parse(true);
    VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
    AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
    ap.selectXPath("/div/span[@class='value']/text()");
    int i = ap.evalXPath();
    if (i!=-1)
        Console.WriteLine(vn.toString(i));
```

Comment: <pre><code> <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <updated>2011-01-20T08:33:23Z</updated>
  <title type="html">grgrgr</title>
  - <entry>
    <title type="html">Blog post : Estiatoria</title>
    - <content type="xhtml">
      - <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        - <div class="due">
          <span class="title">Due:</span>
          <span class="value">20 Jan 11</span>
        </div>
      </content>
  </entry>
</feed></pre></code>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guyes I am putting the fragment of the code. The problem is that when I use XPath: //@* I get all the list correctly. Also I tried //@class and it returned the all the class values - OK. But when I put //span[@class='value'] i got blank list. 
Also I've tried several variations and it seems that when I put attribute equal to something //title[@type='html']  I am getting blank list.

```
<feed xmlns="w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <updated>2011-01-20T08:33:23Z</updated>
  <title type="html">grgrgr</title>
  <entry>
    <title type="html">Blog post : Estiatoria</title>
    <content type="xhtml">
      <div xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div class="due">
          <span class="title">Due:</span>
          <span class="value">20 Jan 11</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```